# Anchor Tag Helper for All Routes - a better way

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have a page with way too many parameters to use asp-route-param. But I can't seem to find an easy way to keep any existing parameters in place except the ones I want to change for that specific  link (think of a page with various links that drill down/up for filtering options).

I came up with a method that works, but I was wondering if there were something better that I have not been able to find.

My method consists of getting the full URL:

`var url = GetDisplayUrl()`

and then a method that accepts the url and what you want to change:

```
    public static string GenerateBetterUrl(string url, string queryParam, string paramValue)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        query[queryParam] = paramValue;
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        return uriBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

I have a different version that accepts a dictionary for that case of multi-replacements (e.g., dates).

Am I missing something? This seems like it would be a normal task and baked in. Or is this it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [asp-all-route-data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0#asp-all-route-data) attribute supports the creation of a dictionary of key-value pairs. The key is the parameter name, and the value is the parameter value.

Instead of providing route parameters one-by-one, you can build and provide an entire dictionary instead.

Plus you can get a dictionary of all values that were used to resolve the current route.

```cs
@{
var ambientValues = HttpContext.Features.Get<IRouteValuesFeature>()?.RouteValues;
}
<a asp-page="..." asp-all-route-data="ambientValues" asp-route-oneValue="something">Link</a>
```

Just make sure you put "asp-all-route-data" first.

Comment: That's what I needed (I didn't want to build the dictionary manually). Thanks